# Relatively positioned div takes up space in original location

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, mouseenter

I have a div that is hidden with display:none; then it appears when an icon is hovered over, basically a tooltip.

Everything works great except, when I hover, the tool tip div (which is relatively positioned to show up next to the hovered icon) will show where it supposed to, but also causes the page to 'open space' where the div is actually located.

So the code looks kind of like:

```
    ~included header with menu~
    <div id="page">
      <div id="hidden-tool-tip">Some instructions about whatever</div>
        <div id="para1">
            <p>A bunch of blah blah stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div id="para2">
            <p>A bunch of blah blah stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div id="para3">
            <img src="theInterWebs" id="tool-tip-activator" />
        </div>
    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tool-tip-activator").mouseenter( function () {
        $("#hidden-tool-tip").fadeIn();
    });

    $("#tool-tip-activator").mouseleave(function () {
        $("#hidden-tool-tip").fadeOut();
    });
   </script>
```

CSS:

```
#hidden-tool-tip
{
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 left: 300px;
 display: none;
 width: 300px;
}
```

So the hidden tool tip is in a hidden div at the top of the page. the mouseenter activated image is about half way down the page and I want the tip to appear next to it, which it does. But when mouseenter occurs, a blank space the same height as the tool tip, opens up at the top of the page.

How do I make the space not open?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `position : absolute;` on the tool tip.
Put the tool tip div inside the icon div (the one you hover over) and make that on relative.

http://jsfiddle.net/6MmDu/

Take a look at the example above.

Also, take a look at this tutorial to get some more ideas...
http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/simple-tooltip-with-jquery-only-text/